# mounting partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

I am new to ubuntu. I installed it on 750GB harddisk. My problem is that i am not able to access the sda2 partition of my disk.
below is the output of sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8b61adb8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   200002047   100000000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       200003582  1465147391   632571905    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1452797952  1465147391     6174720   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       200003584  1452797951   626397184   83  Linux
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sda2 is just an extended partition. You cannot access it, it just "holds" sda5 and sda6.

Comment: so how to access sda6?????

Comment: mount it with sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda6 /your/path/to/mount

Comment: It's just a container.